# Like button on my domain

Tags: facebook-like, account

I want to install like buttons on my shop on my own domain. I am not really getting the clue, what a like-button does. As I have an account on facebook also: If someone likes my domain, will this be counted also on my faceboo-site or are these two different things. If yes, can I combine it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you place a Like button on your shop. It will "like" the shop and post that to the Facebook of the person who liked it.  In general with no modifications. F.e. that people like my Facebook site on my domain, thinking, that they like my domain.

Comment: Thank you! This is it, even when I, of course, hoped, that people, that like myshop and people, that like my facebook-account, would only be one pool.

Comment: Can I let them like my facebook-account, letting them think, that it would be my domain?